# Perl Script gets stuck

Tags: regex, perl

I have a folder that contains old files that need to be deleted without deleting the running files.

I have a command in linux to list running files that contains the running file names.

```
{"xxxxxx","235235235.filename",{xxx},xxxx,xxxx,xxxx}
```

I just need the `235235235.filename`s and a script to compare to files in a linux directory and delete the files that don't match, however the directory also has `xxxxxxxxxxx_235235235.filename`s.

Here is where I am at now:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
my $dir = "****";
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die "Could not open $dir: $!\n";
my @allfiles = readdir DIR;
close DIR;

foreach my $oldfiles(@allfiles) {
$oldfiles =~ s/^(?>\N*?_)((?<field3>[^\n\r.]*?)\.str)$/$+{field3}/img;

#print "$oldfiles\n";
}

my $cmd ="****";
#my $cmd ="ls";
my @runEvents = `$cmd`;
chomp @runEvents;
print "done.";
foreach my $running(@runEvents) {
$running =~ s/(?<field2>[0-9a-z]{4}_8[0-9a-z]{2}_[0-9a-z]{2}[a-z][0-9a-z]0[0-9]\.str|PICO_8D[0-9]_2{2}6[0-9]-1{2}\.str)|\{"PID 8[0-9a-z]{2}","/$+{field2}/ig;


        print "$running\n";
}
```

When the last regex is ran I get

> Use of uninitialized value $+("field2"} in substitution iterator at line 24.

Can anyone point me in a good direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding where a regular expression fails, I find [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger) very helpful. It allows you to single-step through a regular expression so you can see where your regular expression is not general enough for your input data.

The input data from your "running events" program is the most interesting here to diagnose why your regular expression fails, but if you have that, putting it into a small test program makes things very simple:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Debugger;

while(<DATA>) {
    s/(?:(?<field2>[0-9A-Za-z]{4}_8[0-9A-Za-z]{2}_[0-9A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z]0[0-9]\.[Ss][Tt][Rr]|[Pp][Ii][Cc][Oo]_8[Dd][0-9]_2{2}6[0-9]-1{2}\.[Ss][Tt][Rr])|\{"[Pp][Ii][Dd] 8[0-9A-Za-z]{2}","|[",0-9ginru{}]{34,$
};

__DATA__
... the data that your shell script outputs ...
```

Also, your regular expression seems to be cut off, can you please update your question with the correct regular expression?

Comment: I used your suggestion and found that my regex was showing that error when it was not matching then stating it could not replace with the field!